# Grails3 with application.groovy shows mangled pages in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-3.0

I have created an Grails 3(.1.0) application.

When I did the following steps:

- Replace the default `application.yaml` with an equivalent `application.groovy`
- Generate a war-file
- Deploy war-file in Tomcat 8(.0.30)
- Open the application page (`http://localhost:8080`)

Then I got a page that misses all styling and javascript.[image: Blank Grails page]

What am I doing wrong?
Is something wrong with my `application.groovy`?

```
grails {
    profile = "web"
    codegen {
        defaultPackage = "empty31"
    }
}

info {
    app {
        name = 'empt31'
        version = '0.1'
        grailsVersion = '3.1.0'
    }
}

spring {
    groovy {
        template['check-template-location'] = false
    }
}

server {
    contextPath = '/empty31'
}

grails {
    mime {
        disable {
            accept {
                header {
                    userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
                }
            }
        }

        types {
            all = '*/*'
            atom = 'application/atom+xml'
            css = 'text/css'
            csv = 'text/csv'
            form = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            html = ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml']
            js = 'text/javascript'
            json = ['application/json', 'text/json']
            multipartForm = 'multipart/form-data'
            rss = 'application/rss+xml'
            text = 'text/plain'
            hal = ['application/hal+json', 'application/hal+xml']
            xml = ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
        }
    }
    urlmapping {
        cache {
            maxsize = 1000
        }
    }
    controllers {
        defaultScope = 'singleton'
    }
    converters {
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
    views {
        'default' { codec = 'html' }
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml'
            codecs {
                expression = 'html'
                scriptlets = 'html'
                taglib = 'none'
                staticparts = 'none'
            }
        }
    }
}

endpoints {
    jmx['unique-names'] = true
}

hibernate {
    cache {
        queries = false
        use_second_level_cache = true
        use_query_cache = false
        region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    }
}

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = 'sa'
    password = ''
}

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = 'create-drop'
            url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = 'update'
            url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = 'update'
            url = 'jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'
            properties {
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = 'SELECT 1'
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = 'ConnectionState'
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you revert to application.yml?

Comment: Was on my way today to test both versions (.groovy and .yml) and add screenshots with Chrome DevTools panel open. But problems with other software we support took all my time. Will test further on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something went haywire with your asset pipeline. Try grails run-app or run the war directly - if that works thats probably an asset pipeline bug we once avoided by skipping a grails version (something like from 3.0.3 to 3.0.7).

You can also try and disable the bundling with grails.assets.bundle=false and see if that helps for the moment ;)

Check your gradle.build for

```
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

dependencies {
    ...
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
    ...
}
```

It would also be interesting if reverting to application.yml fixes the problem since this bug may have occured at a time where we introduced the spring security core plugin which brings an application.groovy out of the box...

**EDIT1:**
Here the asset versions we are currently working with

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.0.20'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline' version '2.5.0'
}
```

Comment: grails run-app works correctly. I also tried going back to the asset plugin 3.0.1 as suggested as a work around in a grails issue, but that didn't help. Will try the grails.assets.bundle=false

Comment: I added grails.assets.bundle=false to the application.groovy, but still the same result

Comment: Reverting back to the application.yml is not really an option, because we want to use both the joda-time plugin as the sprint-security-core plugin. And at least for the joda-time plugin I don't know how to map the 'user-type' mappings using .yml (as it is a Closure by default)

Comment: I edited my "answer since the config is bit big for a comment ;)

Comment: Why don't you use both `yml` and `groovy`? Just use original yml and additional `application.groovy` for joda config